# VBA bad syntax in dlookup function with global variables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using 8 similar functions in my code and they all work, but this one is not working:

```
global_var_13=DLookup("[amount]", "[tabla amortizacion real]","[no contract]= get_global('global_var_10') and [ident]=get_global('global_var_11') and [cuota]= get_global('global_var_12')")
```

`var_10` is a string, `var_11`, `var_12`, and `var_13` are numeric.

The values are `var_10= "GAF-27/2013"`, `var_11=1`, `var_12=1`

`global_var_13` is returning NULL

Any thoughts about the syntax?

Comment: This simply means that there is no record matching the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate the clause elements:

```
global_var_13 = DLookup("[amount]", "[tabla amortizacion real]", "[no contract] = '" & get_global("global_var_10") & "' and [ident] = " & get_global("global_var_11") & " and [cuota] = " & get_global("global_var_12") & "")
```